# Project with path ':unimodules-core' could not be found in project ':@unimodules_react-native-adapter'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Taking over RN project from another developer and trying to make a build for Android, however Gradle keeps giving me this issue:

`ERROR: Project with path ':unimodules-core' could not be found in project ':@unimodules_react-native-adapter'.`

The only *solution* I could find regarding this is adding settings.gradle file:

```
include ':@unimodules_react-native-adapter'
project(':@unimodules_react-native-adapter').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@unimodules/react-native-adapter/android')
```

but this doesn't work for me.

I have linked the native dependecies
I have tried npm and yarn

Project is using:

```
 "@unimodules/core": "^3.0.2",
 "@unimodules/react-native-adapter": "^3.0.0",
```

Gradle is directing me to the `@unimodules/react-native-adapter/android/build.gradle` file:

```
apply from: project(":unimodules-core").file("../unimodules-core.gradle")
```

Any guidance of what could possible be wrong, would greatly be appreciated

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: hi, yes i solved it. check last answer on this page.

Answer (score 4):

Something that solved this for me was removing: `@unimodules/react-native-adapter` from dependencies entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by installing react-native-unimodules.

$> yarn add react-native-unimodules

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it by deleting project, cloning it again and only running yarn instead of trying npm and yarn.

Comment: i only used yarn, i have no idea, but thats what i did to get it working

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you can try using `npm` to:

1- Remove from your `package.json`

this line:
`"@unimodules/core": "^3.0.2",`

on `"dependencies": {` part

2- Install the `unimodules-core` package:

with npm:

```
npm install @unimodules/core --save
```

you can do identical thing with  `yarn` , you can take a look to the official doc:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unimodules/core?activeTab=readme

Answer (score -1):

For me, the issue was using expo packages (e.g. "import * as Crypto from 'expo-crypto"). I removed them and the problem went away.